# XML Schema, pattern restriction - what is \w?

Tags: validation, xsd, pcre, xmllint

An XSD is containing this line to restrict an attribute:

```
<xsd:pattern value="buyer_specific|customer_specific|duns|iln|gln|party_specific|supplier_specific|\w{1,250}"/>
```

If a custom attribute containing an underscore is used, validation with xmllint fails:

```
Schemas validity error :[...] The value 'checkout_profile' is not accepted by the pattern 'buyer_specific|customer_specific|duns|iln|gln|party_specific|supplier_specific|\w{1,250}'.
```

So what exactly is meant by `\w`? The XSD specification is surprisingly silent about this topic.
https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#key-typeRestriction mentions `pattern`, but I could not find any definition for its meaning. In my eyes patterns are meant to be PCREs, and Perl states in `pcrepattern(3)`:

```
\w     any "word" character
[...]
A "word" character is an underscore or any character that is a letter or digit.
```

So as far as I can say, `checkout_profile` should be fine. Who is to blame? Is this a bug in `xmllint(1)`? Or am I missing an important point somewhere?

Comment: See https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#dt-regex for the format definition of the regular expression language in XSD 1.1 (although I am not sure xmllint support 1.1)

Comment: @MartinHonnen, thanks, missed that. G.4.2.5 is quite clear, so most likely xmllint, i.e. libxml2, is to blame (at least in the version of Debian/stable). Bad luck, might have been easier to get the XSD corrected if it were wrong.

Comment: So perhaps `[\w_]{1,250}` would work.

Comment: In fact this works, but I'll have to convince the author of a published standard to change something which is not really wrong. Ok... far beyond the scope of this question.